# Cancel file in file selection box with jquery button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

With jquery button click i need to cancel(drop, discard) **file that i choose to upload**

Here is my jquery code:

```
     $('.upic9').bind('click', { imgId: $(this).attr('id') }, function (evt) {
     $('.fileselectionbox').empty();  
     });
```

Comment: I'm so confused. I feel like I jumped into the end of a conversation.

Comment: what are you trying to discard? what are you trying to discard it from? what does discard mean in this context?

Comment: the question is not really clear, what are you trying to discard? $. discard() doesn't exits in jQuery, so it's definitely confuse people.

Comment: you code still looks bad!

Comment: this is theory, i dont know how to write this correctly, maybe there is some command that allow to do this

Comment: do you want to hide name of file from form file element?

Comment: no i want to DROP that element, just cancel my file selection with jquery button

Comment: ahhh, you added (selected) few files, and now you want to drop file from list, before submit form, correct?

Comment: yes! i updated my question with more correct words i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery File Upload plugin

I guess this can works in your case.

[jQuery File Upload plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

probably this code example will help you.

I'm not sure if html5 works for your case, if not see link above

```
$('#html5FileInput').fileupload({
    ....
    add: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var newFileDiv = $(newfileDiv(file.name));
            $('#fsUploadProgressHtml5').append(newFileDiv);

            newFileDiv.find('a').bind('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var uploadFilesBox = $("#fsUploadProgressHtml5");
                var remDiv = $(document.getElementById("fileDiv_" + event.data.filename));
                removeFileFromArray(event.data.filename);
                remDiv.remove();
                data.files.length = 0;
                ...
            });

            data.context = newFileDiv;
        });
     ...
)};
```

or see [this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/clear-upload-file-input-field-jquery/)

Comment: i know this solution, but i have my complete written file uploader and now i found this bug, so, im trying to resolve it with one line of code that deletes my selected file but not removes file selection box

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gd8Cu/    < my new code doesn't work, i post old one, but still onclick on img that img needs to be cancled

Comment: here you go, that helped me a lot!